# How to echo something in a separate page

Tags: php

I do not know if this is possible but on this page I have this code below:

```
$moduleHTML  = "";  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
    $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$dbModuleId'>" . $dbModuleId . " - " . $dbModuleName . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
    $outputmodule = ""; 
        $outputmodule .= "<p><strong>Module:</strong> " . $dbModuleId .  " - "  . $dbModuleName . "</p>"; 
}
```

But I want to echo the variable `$outputmodule` in another page. So below is the code for the other page which included the ajax which links the the script above (module.php) and where it contains the echo and where it contains part of the module drop down menu:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function getModules() { 
    var course = jQuery("#coursesDrop").val(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').empty(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "post", 
    url:  "module.php", 
    data: { course:course }, 
    success: function(response){ 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
    } 
    }); 


    }


    </script> 

...

<?

$moduleHTML = "";  
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
$moduleHTML .= '</select>';

echo $outputmodule;

...
```

Problem is that I am receiving an undefined error for the echo above. My question is that how can I echo the `$dbModuleId and $dbModuleName` from the module.php page into the editsession.php page (script above)?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to store the value in a $_SESSION variable. That could be messy though and you'd have to reset the $_SESSION value after your done with it.

Comment: You can redirect to the other page with the value of the var in the URL: http://site.tld/?var=yourvarcontent then read the value of var with $_GET['var'] in the new page. Idk if security is a concern, if it is, I don't recommend this method.

Comment: Is there a way that instead of the ajax actually navigating to a separate page to be able to retreive the drop down values for the "Modules" drop down menu, if I put the code from the module.php page into the same page as the editsession.php page, can I somehow get the ajax to access that drop down menu within the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to use sessions you could pass back your values as a json array then decode it  and append your values  with jquery

```
   $outputArray = array();  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
        $outputArray['moduleHTML'] = "<option value='$dbModuleId'>" . $dbModuleId . " - " . $dbModuleName . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

        $outputArray['outputModule']  = "<p><strong>Module:</strong> " . $dbModuleId .  " - "  . $dbModuleName . "</p>"; 
    } 
    echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

Then on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getModules() { 
    var course = jQuery("#coursesDrop").val(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').empty(); 
    jQuery('#modulesDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url:  "module.php", 
        data: { course:course }, 
        success: function(response){
            var outputjQuery.parseJSON(response)
            jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(output.moduleHTML); 
            jQuery('#outputModule').html(output.outputModule); 
       });
    }); 


}


</script> 

...

<?

$moduleHTML = "";  
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
$moduleHTML .= '</select>';
$moduleHTML .= '<div id="outPutModule"></div>;

echo $moduleHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the php scripts called during different requests, or are they included with each other? If different requests, you can store the variable in $_SESSION and have it available between requests. If within the same request, then the variable will be available either by being in the same scope, or you can use the global keyword to share across scope.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Globals aren't usually recommended. And there's the globals array thing. Just depends on whether you are within the same request.

Comment: Hi, the jquery is called depending on what the user selects from the "Course" drop down menu in the editsession.php page. When the user selects an option from the "Course" drop down menu, it then uses the ajax to access the module.php page and display the values in the "Modules" drop down menu change depending on the course chosen. So what does that mean I should do?